# Setting project specific gradle_user_home via project build/config files

Tags: gradle

While working on a very large multi-module gradle project (300+ modules) I am looking for a way to have a project specific default for the `gradle_user_home` used in the build to point to the `.gradle` directory under the project root. I am not that much interested in the gradle home itself as in its dependency cache being under that path.

I am looking for a way to accomplish this via a setting in a file within the project tree itself, which can be committed to the SCM (e.g. `settings.gradle`, `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, something under `buildSrc` or, if nothing else, in `gradle.properties`). It must be a solution that would require no further manual intervention (no command line option, no global `gradle.properties` etc).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Ideally, the setting should be placeable outside of the `gradle.properties` of the project as I do not want that to be committed keeping it for user-specific adjustments.

Comment: May I ask what your reason is wanting to doing that?

Comment: A necessity to be able to deliver a fully buildable codebase that would also contain everything it needs to build. Additionally, contingency when running multiple builds in parallel on the same build server: we have observed gradle cache locks leading to failures.

Comment: Ah, ok, we don't have this problem as we use TeamCity with multiple build agents and one build agent always only runs one build in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the following into the project `gradle.properties` has worked for me (also applies to the build logic within `buildSrc`):

```
systemProp.gradle.user.home=./.gradle
```

However, as stated in the question I would strongly prefer this outside of `gradle.properties` if possible.

Comment: I don't think there is a different way besides specifying it on the commandline. Except maybe via environment variable, but I guess this is also not what you want.

Comment: Yes, if I find nothing better I will commit the `gradle.properties` file and will make devs put their custom settings into `gradle.properties` under the gradle user home, that is `projectRoot/.gradle` in the above setup

Comment: You could also have a look at `net.saliman.properties` plugin. I have central settings in `gradle.properties` and individual persons can stuff their stuff into `gradle-local.properties` or if they want `gradle-<anything>.properties` where I made `<anything>` configurable with a project property. Btw. I personally as user of a build would greatly dislike if my Gradle user home is not where it is supposed to be. e. g. it waists space if Gradle needs to cache lilbs multiple times and other things. I'd suggest only doing this for the build servers where you actually have the problem.